# Batch Rename Files using Folder Name?

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking to create a script which will rename all images in a folder after the name of the folder they are in. This would be used to rename multiple folders worth of images at once since I'm using it to standardize the naming scheme of all my comics. So I would have say 75 *.cbz's ill unarchive in a directory, then I'd run said script from within a folder containing the sub folders which contain the images that make up each comic to rename every image.

The structure would for example be:

PageRenamer.bat

Series Name 000 (Year)\

Name pg1.jpg, Name pg2.jpg... Name pg24.jpg

Series Name 001 (Year)\

Series Name 001 000.jpg, Series Name 001 001.jpg... Series Name 001 025.jpg

Etc...

The end result I'm looking for is that after you run the script every image is named `Series Name 001 (Year) 000.jpg` - `Series Name 001 (Year) 025.jpg` (number of pages/images may vary) and dwells in the `Series Name 001 (Year)\` folder. Now this is all hoping my comics are single layer archives. It'd be even better if there was a way to integrate the ability to move any images in sub folders within each sub folder(comic root) to the root sub folder (comic root). 
Example:

PageRenamer.bat

Series Name 000 (Year)\

Series Name 000\

Name pg1.jpg, Name pg2.jpg... Name pg24.jpg

Series Name 001 (Year)\

Series Name 001\

Series Name 001\

Series Name 001 000.jpg, Series Name 001 001.jpg... Series Name 001 025.jpg

Etc...

Changing it to match the format of example 1 (including deleting the now unused sub folders). Any help is very welcome I'll be happy to get a script simple enough to do the first task since most comics are one layer. It'd be a huge bonus if I wouldn't have to worry about fixing the ones that aren't.

Comment: What does your current script look like, and what issues do you have with it? (posts tend to be closed unless you've shown what you've already tried, and what problems you've encountered)

Comment: Well I've searched and searched and I've found 100 different ways to rename them all with a (1)-(25) numbering scheme but that's both ugly and not as functional as a 000-025 scheme. I can't find anyway to number them this way without brackets. I could write some bs script I know won't work but I don't see the point since a script to do this properly will be completely different. I also have no idea how to archive moving the images to each folders root but that's a bonus line of code as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Binaryatrocity's code is exactly where I'm at I can't figure out how to make that simple code do this task properly. Specifically using the folders name and numbering the images 000-025 rather then the default (1)-(26) that's used when renaming multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just throw a few lines of batch script in here to point you in the right direction. You can start with a forloop like this, which will list all of the subdirectories in your comic folder:

```
  for /d %%D in (*) do
```

Then have a second forloop in there, to take all the .jpg's in each subdirectory and rename them:

```
for %%f in (*.jpg) do (
       #here you will want to craft a string for the filename, using the subdirectory name (%D)
       ren "%%F" "your-crafted-string.jpg"
 )
```

You'll need to track a variable to store the # of files you've processed for naming:

```
 set /A num=0
```

You can increment this each loop run in the inner loop:

```
 set /A num+=1
```

And reset it for each increment of the outer loop (each subdirectory):

```
 set /A num=0
```

Crafting a string inside the innermost loop for each file would look something like this (untested):

```
 ren "%%F" "!%%D%_%num%!.jpg"
```

You can read this as `rename [the file] as "[Directory name]_[value of num].jpg"

Comment: Thanks for your help but these are the basic things I already knew but am unable to find a way to make it work. Specifically because I want a 000-025 numbering scheme (actually starting at 0)  instead of a (1)-(26) scheme. Plus I have no knowledge of string manipulation or how to write a string that would use the folder name. Could you help with that? I use a lot of renaming scripts I've written but they are all simple ones that either change things before or after the "." That marks the extension.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us what you've tried? I'd be happy to help figure out where your getting hung up.

Comment: I've always renamed/moved/deleted things with very specific names or extensions to something else specific or based on the files original name. I have no idea how to setup the variables in this instance to use the folder name and or number things in a 000 formate.

Comment: I've updated the answer a tad to get you going! Best of luck.

Comment: No luck so far here's what I'm trying. @for /r %%f in (*.jpg) do ( set /A num=000 ren "%%F" "!%%D% %num%!.jpg" set /A num+=1)

Comment: Sorry about the formatting I'm coding on my PC and posting from my iPhone because I don't have wifi.