# Rename files recursively with name of the containing folder and number

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rename, subdirectory

I found some threads with quite similar questions here, but not exactly what I want to do:
I have a folder with 11 subfolders containing about 50 subfolders each, containing about 50.000 `.jpg` files in total.

Now I'd like to rename the `.jpg` files using this pattern:

```
[name of the containing subfolder][underscore][specific word][underscore][increasing number].jpg
```

I'd like to do this with a `.cmd` batch file (Win7).

Example:

Before:

```
2003
   -folder1
       -img (1).jpg
       -img (2).jpg
       -img (3).jpg
   -folder2
       -otherimage (1).jpg
       -otherimage (2).jpg
   -folder3
        -...
2004
2005
...
```

After running the batch with "test" as the specific word:

```
img (1).jpg -> folder1_test_1.jpg
img (2).jpg -> folder1_test_2.jpg
img (3).jpg -> folder1_test_3.jpg
otherimg (1).jpg -> folder2_test_1.jpg
otherimg (2).jpg -> folder2_test_2.jpg
```

It would be ok to start the batch from each first level folder (2003, 2004...) to rename all the files in the subfolders included.

I was trying to solve it by myself over an hour now using the hints from other threads ([Batch Rename Files using Folder Name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919796/batch-rename-files-using-folder-name)), but it didn't work. I'm not familiar with the syntax of batch programming at all, but I have to solve this task anyhow...

Answer (score 0):

(Question answered by OP edit. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP Wrote:

> At last, I found a freeware tool for Windows that does exactly what I need:
>   http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php